# What value doe the FileExists method return?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use the FileExists method in VBScript and the value being returned is not Boolean as per all the documentation that I've read.  I've run the following script on Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2003 and instead of returning True or False, it returns a -1 if the file exists or 0 if the file does not exist.

```
Dim oFile, vFile
Set oFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
vFile = "C:\pagefile.sys"
WScript.Echo oFile.FileExist(vFile)
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks,

TB

Comment: Did you check what -1 or 0 would mean in the VBScript documentation? Maybe -1 is true and 0 is false.

Comment: In Visual Basic, `true` is -1 and `false` is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.FileExists returns a variant of boolean sub-type. Drawing conclusions from output can be misleading, especially if your output agent is the stupid WScript.Echo:

```
>> fe = GoFS.FileExists("00.vbs")
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(fe), fe, CStr(fe), CStr(-1)
>>
Boolean -1 True -1
```

At least CStr() knows enough about sub-types to differentiate between -1 (which isn't True, but something that is interpreted as True in some contexts) and true True.

Comment: Thanks for the input and that answered my question.  I wasn't aware of that difference between WScript.Echo and MsgBox as MsgBox translates the returned values to True or False.  Also thanks to johnhopkins for his helpfull insight.

Answer (score 0):

The `WScript.Echo oFile.FileExist(vFile)` is missing an "s". It should be

```
WScript.Echo oFile.FileExists(vFile).
```

Comment: That's a good catch. It might just be a typo in his question though, since he is getting valid results from the script. But for future reference, "answers" like this (does not answer the question being directly asked) are more of a comment and shouldn't be posted as an answer. I know you don't have the reputation to post comments yet and it's annoying to have something to say when you can't, and I'm guilty of doing the same thing when I got started here, but just don't be surprised if this is removed by a moderator.

Comment: Thanks for the response but even after correcting my typo and using "FileExists", it still does not return a Boolean value.

Comment: Suresh is correct. You can check it by executing "WScript.Echo True" and it will echo "-1".